# Globally accessible variable for setting paths - Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, environment-variables, production

setting up Laravel 4 and looking for a way too sort out the base path for local vs live development.

My website currently runs on 'www.project.com' and then I access the site on local machine as 'localhost:8888/project'.

For things such as CSS and image paths etc I am looking for a way to have a variable for the base paths so I dont have to manually go changing paths etc when switching to live host.

I currently use the environment for my database settings:

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(array(

    'local' => array('MacBook.local'),
    'production' => array('project.com'),

));
```

Can I work with something similar to this so its all done automatically?

My css paths in my template blade file are:

```
'/css/main.css'
```

And then on local:

'/project/public_html/css/main.css'

Unless there is a way to get the route of what I am trying to do with PHP?

Thanks.

Comment: I recommend you generate all your asset urls with the [asset function](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/helpers#urls). Then it should be all fine, no matter on which host you are.

Comment: another way to tackle it is, use virtual hosts if you are on apache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use something like this:

```
<!--Blade-->
<link href="{{ asset('css/main.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" />

<!--Non-Blade-->
<link href="<?php echo asset('css/main.css') ?>" rel="stylesheet" />
```

This will solve the problem. Check the `asset` helper function on the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/helpers#paths).

Answer (score 0):

You could use `App::environment()` to check the current environment and then set the appropriate base path for all assets using the html [base](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) tag. Then, whenever you want to reference an asset, just reference it relative to this base path and the browser will do the rest.

This way, you'd end up with something like:

Production:

```
<base href="http://www.project.com/">
```

Local:

```
<base href="http://localhost:8888/project/public_html/">
```

Obviously you'd want to use Laravel's URL functions to build these URLs rather than hard-code them though...